# stack alert notifier for multiple browsers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-promotion, notifications

I am not sure if I am the last, but I am sure there may be many here who might not  know there is a cool stack alert extension available. The alert extension sits in the top corner of the browser that notifies if there are new comments/notifications. I personally found it very useful to stay in touch with all the notifications.

Link : https://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing

A personal enhancement request to display it on the sites side bar/ somewhere flashy so that people would download it and use this site better. IMHO this would increase the latency we have before people see that the posts have been answered/comments being posted related to the topic :)

I also wanted to know if there was an email service to subscribe to if there were any updates available/ notifications/ new posts?

Experts please let me know your thoughts!!!

Comment: Added featured tag so this question appears in the 'Community Bulletin' sidebar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the StackExchange menu (top left), then email settings at the bottom of the popup - you can have unread inbox messages sent to you as often as every 3 hours.